# Finding the step in a step function in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to solve an optimization problem with a step function. A heavily simplified version would be:

```python
def stepfunc(x):
    value=30
    if x<=30:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I am looking to find the step which is obviously 30 in this case. The real world function is of course way more complicated.
I came up with the following approaches to solve for the step value:

1. Itterating from 0 to a higher number, check when the result becomes false and live with the small error induced by the stepping
2. A little more sophiticated by searching from two sides (code not optimized but should show the idea)

```python
step=1
x=2
#find lower and upper bounds
xl=x-step
xu=x+step
yl=y=yu=True
while(yl==y==yu):
    y=stepfunc(x)
    yl=stepfunc(xl)
    yl=stepfunc(xu)
    step=step*10
    xl=x-step
    if(xl<0):
        xl=0
    xu=x+step
#continue with xl and xu
for i in range(20):
    x=((xu-xl)/2)+xl
    y=stepfunc(x)
    yl=stepfunc(xl)
    yl=stepfunc(xu)
    if(y): #mean value gives True
        xl=x
    else:
        xu=x
    #print([xl,x,xu])
print("The step is at " + str(x))
```

While this is working I am rather sure that there is a better solution in one of the optimization libraries. I tried to use a few of the scipy solvers without succcess and I am propably using the wrong search terms. Is there a library that can be used easily here?

Comment: I there a single step or many? Can you provide a graphical representation of the function output for a reasonable range of input?

Comment: You might start with an interval `[a,b]` where the function is True at one side and False at the other.  And then divide the interval into 2 (`m = (a+b)/2`, and depending on the function value for `m` continue either with `[a,m]` or `[m,b]`. You stop when the difference between `a` and `b` is very small.

Comment: If a single value, this is actually a simple binary search (as described by @JohanC), it gets more interesting for multiple steps although this remains a similar principle

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. The "binary search" as suggested by @mozway is indeed what I was looking for and `scipy.optimize.brentq` will do it. This will however require to return -1 and 1 instead of True and False. In total the revised problem with solution is

```python
import scipy.optimize

# step function which returns -1 or 1 depending on which side of the step we are
def stepfunc(x):
    unknown_value_to_look_for=30 # in the real world function this number is unknown
    if(x<=unknown_value_to_look_for):
        return -1
    else:
        return 1
    
#find upper limit; lower limit is set to "0"
upper=1
for i in range(100): #max 100 tries
    if(stepfunc(upper)==1):
        break
    upper*=10

# upper is 100 in this example
scipy.optimize.brentq(stepfunc,0,upper,disp=True)
```